# Refresh search result with angular instantSearch

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch

I have integrated algolia with angular instantsearch according to the following documentation.

https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/getting-started.html

Everything is working fine so far except the one. For example, initially there are 10 data in my algolia indices. From backend, I inserted a few more data. My "ais-instantsearch", does not display the new data until I click on the browser refresh button.

As it is a single page application, I need some way to refresh the dataset. I do not know which function of ais-instantsearch I need to trigger to refresh my result dataset.

Has there any function to refresh the dataset?

Comment: Having the same issue at the moment. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes, it has fixed in version 2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I post this issue, that time the latest version was 2.0.2

https://github.com/algolia/angular-instantsearch/releases

And after a bit more analysis, I found instant search itself has a `refresh()` method, which has not implemented in angular-instantsearch properly. Then I reported the following issue. https://github.com/algolia/angular-instantsearch/issues/185

And then next version 2.0.3, it has fixed by Haroenv.